# Running specific JavaScript/jQuery functions on certain pages

Tags: jquery

Would it be wiser to check if a particular element exists on the page?

```
if ($('#cool-page').length > 0) {
    // my jQuery function
}
```

Or check if the window location is the correct page?

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('words-here') != -1) {
    // my jQuery function
}
```

In this situation, I only want to run my jQuery function on pages: `site.com/123/words-here`

If the best way is the latter, how should I be writing up a regexp to match the location above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the body element a class or an id:

```
<body class="cool-page">
```

Then use jQuery:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('cool-page')) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you only want it to run on a particular page, `window.location.href` seems like a safer bet and more indicative of your purpose for running the method.  Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would give each pages body a specific id such as

`<body id="cool-page">`

and using jquery/javascript I would use a switch to wrap the specific functions

```
var pageid = $('body').attr('id');
switch(pageid)​ {
    case 'cool-page':
        //dosomething
        break;
        default:
        //dosomething
        break;
    }​
```